# Queueing Theory: Router question

Tags: queueing-theory

I have this question I am struggling with:

> Suppose that packet interarrival time and packet service times at a router follow an exponential probability density function and the router will be handling a mean arrival of 2500 packets per second.
>
> Suppose that the router has 1MB of memory for its incoming queue and is
> processing 2700 packets per second on average. The average packet size is 1KB. The network
> administrator needs to tune the router to use some CPU time for other tasks like routing for
> network management. If the network administrator is comfortable with at most 80% of the
> queue memory space used (on average) then what percentage of CPU time can be used for
> these other tasks?

I am really not sure if I got this concept right, so here is my solution and my questions:

1MB memory

µ = 2700

Average packet size: 1KB = 1024 bytes

%80 memory space = 0.8 * 1MB = 838861 bytes

N = 819 (number of packets the queue can hold)

From this point I assumed the arrival is the same with part a, λ=2500. I also assumed that my CPU time is 2700 in total and all used if 1mb queue is %100 used.

My reasoning is that: what CPU time(out of 2700) would I need to maintain the N=819 packets in the queue with 2500 arrival time?

So I used N = λ / (µ - λ) and found µ=2503

Then I would have 2503/2700 * 100 = %93 which means I have %7 CPU time left for other stuff.

Is this how I am supposed to interpret and solve this question? I have a feeling that I am totally off the track or I am missing something. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing "at most 80% of the queue memory space used (on average)" strikes me as rather unclear. You might want to ask for clarification about exactly what that means, I will offer one interpretation here.

The model described is an [M/M/1 queue with 
finite capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue) with a state space like that shown below.

[image]

You have an arrival rate $\lambda = 2500$ packets per second and a potential service rate $\mu =2900$ packets per second. The M/M/1/$n$ model has storage space for $N$ jobs, so as 1MB = 1024 KB we set $n=1024$. For this model now we can compute the average number of jobs in the system. (I'll leave that for you to do.)

What the question asks is what value of $p$ can we choose (setting the service rate to be $\mu = 2900p$) such that the average number of customers in the system is 80% (i.e. 819). You need to use the calculation I left as an exercise above to compute the average number of jobs in the system as a function of $p$ and then choose the value of $p$ which sets the average number of jobs in the system to be 80%.

If this question is homework please tag it as such. The question feels rather unclear, perhaps you can double check your source?